# Developing a Shiny App that pulls IRT analysis from MIRT Package into Table and Plot format

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a new user of Shiny and am trying to build an app within a dashboard that does three things.

1. Accept a csv data file from the user of the app - this seems to work fine as I get a message within the app that the "Upload complete"
2. Generate a plot output based on the data file using the mirt package
3. Generate a table output based on the data file using the mirt package.

When I upload a csv data file I get the following error for both the plot and table outputs:

Error: argument is of length zero

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel(p("Let's Analyze with IRT!", style = "color:teal")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     h3("Upload Your Data"), 
      h5(em("Remember your data should be a matrix with dichotomous responses of 0 or 1 stored in a .csv file")),
     fileInput(inputId = "filedata",
          label = "Choose csv file",
          accept = c(".csv")), 
                 p("Made with", a("Shiny",
                 href = "http://shiny.rstudio.com")),
                 img(src = base64enc::dataURI(file = xxx, 
                                              mime = "image/png"))),
  mainPanel("ICC Plot and Item Parameter Table",
           tableOutput("irtPT")
            )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  mydata <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath,  header = FALSE)
  })

  output$irtPT <- renderTable({
    unimodel <- mirt.model("latent = ")

    modT2 <- mirt::mirt(data = mydata,
               model = unimodel,
               itemtype = "Rasch",
               SE = TRUE)

    coef.rasch3 <- coef(modT2, IRTpars=TRUE, simplify=TRUE)

    items.rasch3 <- as.data.frame(coef.rasch3$items)

    IR3e <- items.rasch3 %>% select(-c("g", "u"))

    colnames(IR3e)[1] <- "Item Discrimination Parameter"
    colnames(IR3e)[2] <- "Item Location Parameter"

    print(IR3e)
  }, rownames = TRUE)
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for including your code, but note that to make it as easy as possible for people to help you, you should make your code as small as possible, and make sure that it will work on someone else's computer (who may not have your files etc). This can take some practice though :) In this case, your code immediately broke for me, because you had an `img()` that I don't have on my computer, so better to leave that out completely. See example below, and note library call first as well:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Let's Analyze with IRT!", style = "color:teal")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h3("Upload Your Data"), 
            h5(em("Remember your data should be a matrix with dichotomous responses of 0 or 1 stored in a .csv file")),
            fileInput(inputId = "filedata",
                      label = "Choose csv file",
                      accept = c(".csv")), 
            p("Made with", a("Shiny",
                             href = "http://shiny.rstudio.com"))#,
            ## These lines break
            # img(src = base64enc::dataURI(file = xxx, 
            #                              mime = "image/png"))
            ),
        mainPanel("ICC Plot and Item Parameter Table",
                  tableOutput("irtPT")
        )
    )
)
```

To answer your question, your uploaded CSV data is a reactive object, so you need to call it like a function. Read here for some more details: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html

To fix your code, all you need to do is change `mydata` to `mydata()` in the `mirt()` function. I.e. your server function looks like this:

```r
server <- function(input, output){
    mydata <- reactive({
        req(input$filedata)
        read.csv(input$filedata$datapath,  header = FALSE)
    })
    
    output$irtPT <- renderTable({
        unimodel <- mirt.model("latent = ")
        
        modT2 <- mirt::mirt(data = mydata(),  
                                  # ^ Changed from mydata
                            model = unimodel,
                            itemtype = "Rasch",
                            SE = TRUE)
        
        coef.rasch3 <- coef(modT2, IRTpars=TRUE, simplify=TRUE)
        
        items.rasch3 <- as.data.frame(coef.rasch3$items)
        
        IR3e <- items.rasch3 %>% select(-c("g", "u"))
        
        colnames(IR3e)[1] <- "Item Discrimination Parameter"
        colnames(IR3e)[2] <- "Item Location Parameter"
        
        print(IR3e)
    }, rownames = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the quick response and code help! I've adjusted the mydata to mydata() as you suggested, but now when running the app I get the error message: "Input data must be integer or numeric only". My csv file is numeric as far as I can tell. Do you have any advice on how to fix this? I tried making the data file numeric using as.numeric, but that threw a different error and didn't help.

Comment: I believe this is to do with the mirt function. According to the documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mirt/versions/1.38.1/topics/mirt) it requires a numeric matrix or data frame. So you will need to add some logic in to make sure that your uploaded CSV is all numeric, or converted to a data frame. At this point it's often helpful to run the function locally (not in shiny) to make sure it works on a test dataset, and then work on making it robust for other cases, and then integrate into the shiny app.